# xxx.replace() not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, api, replace

At the moment I'm getting code from [this api](https://api.roleplay.co.uk/v1/player/76561198062083666) - I'm trying to show list of vehicles in a user friendly way, aka the 'classname', and I've got that running right with the code below:

```
var vehicleList = data.vehicles.map(v => v.classname);       
var content = vehicleList.join(", ");        
document.getElementById("vehicle").textContent = content;
```

However, I want to replace the names of the vehicles with more understandable ones, for example the API might say "B_Quadbike_01" when I really want it to just say "Quadbike" in my html. I've tried doing that with the code below:

```
content.replace(/B_Quadbike_01/ig, "Quadbike");
```

However it's just not working - am I doing it right? You can see what I mean with the vehicle list [over here](http://stats.arni.site/html/player.html?id=76561198062083666) how it just looks like a complete mess.

Comment: You need to show us a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - you haven't given us anything to go on or diagnose.

Comment: @AlexK. you can just do `[ MCVE ]` (without the spaces) and it will make the link for you: [MCVE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` not working on the object it returns the result

You should copy it like this:

```
content = content.replace(/B_Quadbike_01/gi, "Quadbike");
```

[For more information](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Make **all** classes **readable**, for example with all words that have more than **3** characters

```
string.match(/(?:[A-Za-z]{3,})/g)
```

```js
var data = {"uid":169243,"name":"PC Ant Arni","steamid":"76561198062083666","forumname":null,"forumid":null,"forumurl":null,"steam":{"name":"Ant Arni","profileurl":"https:\/\/steamcommunity.com\/id\/Antarni\/","avatarSmall":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/avatars\/25\/25f4a505cbce0a9b1deacb7468e18898bcff484f.jpg","avatarMedium":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/avatars\/25\/25f4a505cbce0a9b1deacb7468e18898bcff484f_medium.jpg","avatarLarge":"https:\/\/steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net\/steamcommunity\/public\/images\/avatars\/25\/25f4a505cbce0a9b1deacb7468e18898bcff484f_full.jpg"},"guid":"33b56e488b3d41d67ff3bc1f57b3d101","cash":0,"bank":11048411,"adminlevel":0,"wanted":false,"groupid":204,"grouprank":3,"groupname":"The Copper Kings","unmcrank":0,"unmcair":0,"unmcranger":0,"unmclastlogin":null,"policerank":3,"npasrank":0,"mporank":2,"arrank":0,"ncarank":0,"rturank":1,"undercoverrank":"0","policelastlogin":"2017-12-03 19:19:15","nhsrank":4,"nhsarrank":0,"nhsrirrank":1,"nhslastlogin":"2017-11-05 21:27:15","civ_licenses":[{"license":"driver","owned":true},{"license":"air","owned":true},{"license":"heroin","owned":true},{"license":"marijuana","owned":true},{"license":"boat","owned":true},{"license":"oil","owned":true},{"license":"dive","owned":true},{"license":"truck","owned":true},{"license":"gun","owned":true},{"license":"rebel","owned":true},{"license":"coke","owned":true},{"license":"diamond","owned":true},{"license":"copper","owned":true},{"license":"plastic","owned":true},{"license":"aluminium","owned":true},{"license":"silica","owned":true},{"license":"iron","owned":true},{"license":"sand","owned":true},{"license":"salt","owned":true},{"license":"cement","owned":true},{"license":"home","owned":true},{"license":"event","owned":false},{"license":"meth","owned":true},{"license":"taxi","owned":true},{"license":"arac","owned":true},{"license":"rebelimports","owned":true}],"vehicles":[{"id":360502,"classname":"B_Quadbike_01_F","type":"Car","color":7},{"id":360505,"classname":"C_Offroad_01_F","type":"Car","color":4},{"id":364532,"classname":"C_Van_01_box_F","type":"Car","color":1},{"id":367013,"classname":"C_Kart_01_Vrana_F","type":"Car","color":0},{"id":373584,"classname":"O_MRAP_02_F","type":"Car","color":0},{"id":386845,"classname":"C_Hatchback_01_sport_F","type":"Car","color":0},{"id":392893,"classname":"C_Scooter_Transport_01_F","type":"Ship","color":3},{"id":393490,"classname":"B_Truck_01_box_F","type":"Car","color":0},{"id":398146,"classname":"O_Plane_CAS_02_F","type":"Air","color":0},{"id":402207,"classname":"B_Truck_01_box_F","type":"Car","color":0},{"id":402335,"classname":"O_LSV_02_unarmed_F","type":"Car","color":1},{"id":407171,"classname":"C_Scooter_Transport_01_F","type":"Ship","color":4},{"id":414610,"classname":"C_Plane_Civil_01_racing_F","type":"Air","color":0},{"id":414696,"classname":"C_Hatchback_01_sport_F","type":"Car","color":3},{"id":415938,"classname":"C_Plane_Civil_01_racing_F","type":"Air","color":0},{"id":415939,"classname":"I_Heli_light_03_unarmed_F","type":"Air","color":2},{"id":419203,"classname":"I_C_Offroad_02_unarmed_F","type":"Car","color":5},{"id":420228,"classname":"B_T_VTOL_01_infantry_F","type":"Air","color":0},{"id":420230,"classname":"B_Heli_Transport_03_unarmed_F","type":"Air","color":0},{"id":420248,"classname":"I_Truck_02_covered_F","type":"Car","color":0},{"id":427634,"classname":"O_MRAP_02_F","type":"Car","color":0},{"id":427635,"classname":"O_Heli_Light_02_unarmed_F","type":"Air","color":3},{"id":427640,"classname":"C_Hatchback_01_sport_F","type":"Car","color":0},{"id":427641,"classname":"O_Heli_Transport_04_bench_F","type":"Air","color":0},{"id":429865,"classname":"I_Truck_02_fuel_F","type":"Car","color":0},{"id":438410,"classname":"C_Plane_Civil_01_racing_F","type":"Air","color":0},{"id":445053,"classname":"B_Heli_Light_01_F","type":"Air","color":14},{"id":445054,"classname":"B_Heli_Light_01_F","type":"Air","color":3},{"id":445857,"classname":"B_T_VTOL_01_infantry_F","type":"Air","color":0},{"id":447813,"classname":"C_Van_02_vehicle_F","type":"Car","color":7},{"id":447814,"classname":"C_Van_02_transport_F","type":"Car","color":7},{"id":448115,"classname":"I_G_Van_02_transport_F","type":"Car","color":0},{"id":448119,"classname":"I_G_Van_02_vehicle_F","type":"Car","color":0},{"id":453900,"classname":"C_Van_01_fuel_F","type":"Car","color":0},{"id":458437,"classname":"O_Plane_Fighter_02_Stealth_F","type":"Air","color":0}]}

var vehicleList = data.vehicles.map(v => v.classname.match(/(?:[A-Za-z]{3,})/g).join("-")); 

var content = vehicleList.join(", ");

document.getElementById("vehicle").textContent = content;
```

```html
<div id="vehicle"></div>
```